# Accept All Certificates for Existing HttpClient Instance

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

In a project containing some legacy code, we need to upgrade the apache `httpclient` dependency from version `4.1.3` to `4.5.3`, which introduced some deprecations and requires us to change how we disable SSL verification for an **existing** HttpClient instance.

Before we did something like

```java
public void disableSSLVerification(HttpClient httpClient) {
    // ... create all-accepting SSLSocketFactory instance
    httpClient
        .getConnectionManager()
        .getSchemeRegistry()
        .register(new Scheme("https", httpsPort, sslSocketFactory));
}
```

I understand that the replacement for this use case is to specify this "accept all" behavior during the HttpClient instance creation using the `HttpClientBuilder` class. However, since we are getting an already-configured `HttpClient` instance, this does not seem to be an option to me.

Are there alternatives to add the "accept all" behavior to an existing `HttpClient` instance without using the builder pattern for `httpclient` `4.5.3`?